# fix the multi time request on full calendar fetch resources

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, fullcalendar

I have a calendar with some custom functions.
The calendar builds once, but in some cases, I need to update the min and max time setting.

To get currect min/max time, I have an ajax function that the return of that is as bellow.
`{"start":"12:00:00","end":"21:30:00"}`

And this response followed by this code to update the calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'minTime', minTime);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'maxTime', maxTime);
```

I have an update calendar data that call the function that fetching the min/max time as well.

```
function updateCalendarData() {

   getCalendarDateField();
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');      
   // min/maxtime function.
   setStudioHours(studioWorkingHours);
}
```

I have some button that by clicking them, the calendar should be updated like bellow.

```
$('#calendar_date').change(function(event , element) {
  updateCalendarData();
});

$('#filter_form_submited').click(function(event , element) {
  updateCalendarData();
});
jQuery('body').on('click','button.fc-prev-button, button.fc-next-button',function(event) {
  setStudioHours(studioWorkingHours);
});

$(document).on('keypress',function(event) {
  if(event.which == 13) {
    updateCalendarData();
  }
});
```

I set the `refetchResourcesOnNavigate` as true, and here is my resource and events callback functions.

```
resources: function(callback){

  timeInfo = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');

  jQuery('input[name="start"], #calendar_date').val(timeInfo.start.format());
  jQuery('input[name="end"]').val(timeInfo.end.format());

  $.ajax({
    url: resourcesCallback,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    data: jQuery('.calendar_filter_form').serialize(),
    error: function() {
      console.log('Oops! Try again.');
    },
    success: function(response){
      $(".fc-widget-header th > div").popover('hide');
      callback(response);
    }
  });
},

events: {
  url: eventsCallback,
  method: 'GET',
  data: function() {
    var fields = jQuery('.calendar_filter_form').serializeArray();
    var datas = {};
    jQuery.each(fields, function(index, val) {
      /* iterate through array or object */
      datas[val.name] = val.value;
    });
    return datas;
  },
  failure: function() {
    alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
  },
},
```

System working fine, without any error, but issue is that resource `called 3 times`.

And I'm sure that I just have the resources and the path or operations are unique. But in my network log, it is 3 times that the related path for ajax request.

So what is wrong, I tried to stop multiple requesting with some true/false value but not working.

Just I should mention that I have Drupal 8, and the v3 of the full calendar.

**UPDATED**

I updated the codes and know I fix the issue of loading multi times on my custom buttons.

```
function updateCalendarData() {
    getCalendarDateField();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    setStudioHours(studioWorkingHours);
}
```

and just one time set the times.

```
var newTimeConfig = {};
newTimeConfig['minTime'] = matchedDayHours.start;
newTimeConfig['maxTime'] = matchedDayHours.end;
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', newTimeConfig);
```

But still, I have an issue with update resources on navigation, that If I make its config false then I will get this error.

`refetchResourcesOnNavigate: false,`

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined

Check this demo https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/gOOMMKN

Comment: The short answer is: setting an an option such as minTime or maxTime causes the calendar to be redrawn. Re-drawing the calendar involves re-drawing the resources. Re-drawing the resources necessarily involves re-fetching the relevant data from the source. I wasn't able to re-create your entire scenario (as there is some info missing like the HTML form, and one of the ajax calls), but a brief experiment confirms that updating min/max Time will cause the resource ajax call to fire:https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abbNPdQ?editors=1010 - click the "set studio times" button and watch the network log

Comment: @ADyson thanks, your answer helps again. I removed the fetched resource instead of that set option does it, and Also merging minTime and maxTime setting to one request decrease 3 fetch resources to one.

Comment: @ADyson Still I have an issue with `refetchResourcesOnNavigate` please check my update on the question.

Comment: It looks like in that scenario it doesn't wait until the view has finished rendering before fetching the resources (because, it doesn't need to know the start and end times, which are supplied to the "resources" function as extra arguments in the case that refetchResourcesOnNavigate is set to true, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/resources-function). So now when you are running your code the view is not fully defined yet, hence the start/end parameters are undefined.